# Android: Image transfer using bluetooth or email

Tags: android, bluetooth, email-attachments

I'm new to Android Development. 
I'm trying to make an application where I load an image, edit and save it, and transfer the image through bluetooth and email.

It seems like Android has a built in tools that I can use to easily implement bluetooth feature, But I couldn't find any easy and straight-forward tutorials yet.

Can someone help me and give me an example or links to a good tutorial regarding bluetooth feature or email feature?

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: There is bluetooth chat app in samples with ADK find it, modify it and done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this below script

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Photo");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/dcim/Camera/filename.jpg"));
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Enjoy the photo");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

Comment: I really like it! Thanks so much. It may sound silly but what does it do when I sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg")?

Comment: it's a content type. you can also use image/* .

Answer (score 0):

With this code, first save file on sdCad, then send it with Bt, email or ...

```
    send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        File newSoundFile = new File("/sdcard/101Ringtone.ogg");
        Uri mUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ RingtoneRaw);
        ContentResolver mCr = getContentResolver();
        AssetFileDescriptor soundFile;
        try {
            soundFile= mCr.openAssetFileDescriptor(mUri, "r");
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               soundFile=null;   
           }

           try {
              byte[] readData = new byte[1024];
              FileInputStream fis = soundFile.createInputStream();
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);
              int i = fis.read(readData);
              while (i != -1) {
                fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                i = fis.read(readData);
              }
              fos.close();
           } catch (IOException io) {
           }

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("audio/ogg");    
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(newSoundFile)); 
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share ringtone via:"));
    }

});
```